# Unity collision detection in specific area of gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am stuck, I have three bowls and catching the falling objects. The issue is I want to catch the distinguished objects in separate bowl. All bowls are connected and transform will moving device. So kindly guide me with possible solution. If any other detail needed then ask me.

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more specific about what you are doing, along with showing some code of what you tried and why it didn't work...

Comment: i am unable to post screen shots due to low reputation. i explain more clearly like i have 3 bowls in line and these bowls are catching the objects that are falling form the screen. i just want to catch apple in 1st bowl tennis ball in 2nd bowl and so on. in negation if i catch wrong object then it will minus the score.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks alot for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   OnTriggerEnter(collider col)
    {
      if(col.gameObject.tag == gameObjcet.tag)
      {
        //do stuff for collecting 
      }else {//do stuff for catching wrong thing}
    }
```

Comment: This method is being used for collision as and it is working. but the point of issue is all three bowls behave like one gameObject not separate. 2ndly after seperation each bowl could only catch its assigned object for catching. thanks @Uri Popov

Comment: Well if they are essentially the "same" gameObject, how would it ever be possible to tell the bowls apart? You'll need to split them up somehow I would think.

Comment: split the bowls as seperate game object  , parent them to a holder object and use your moving logic on the parent object. That way the bowls have seperate colliders and they still move as one

Comment: @DangerZone if i make them separate gameobjects then it creates spawn issue. mean to say each three bowls on collides with the screen end they collapse with each other

Comment: Shouldn't that be fixed by @UriPopov's comment?

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!